# How to change this to return function and remove function declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i know that for some of you this may be dead easy, but I am well confused.
I have been asked to removed function declaration and change this to return function.
Please help.

```
const canViewVisualisation = () => {
     const requiredScopes = [VIEW_ALL_VISUALISATIONS, SITE_ADMIN, ALL];
     const matchingScopes = intersection(requiredScopes, activeScopes);
     return matchingScopes.length !== 0;
   };
```

Comment: what do you mean by "remove function declaration"?

Comment: What is the `intersection`?

Comment: @Greedo like curly brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of anything like "return function". There are void functions and returning functions. The one you posted is already returning something.

There could be one instance I could understand about "return function" - meaning that return function satysfying the shortened arrow function syntax:

```js
const returnArg = arg => arg;
```

Only thing that comes to mind that would satisfy the shortened arrow syntax and a function without a declaration is this:

```js
() => intersection(
    [VIEW_ALL_VISUALISATIONS, SITE_ADMIN, ALL],
    activeScopes
).length !== 0;
```

Which is an "arrow function expression".

Comment: Thank you so much I will learn about it - I know that this is actually basic knowledge  but i needed help asap. thank you so so so much.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this, to find the common elements in two arrays in a single line without the need for a function. If so I think this would help,

```js
const canViewVisualisation = activeScopes.find((scope) => ([VIEW_ALL_VISUALISATIONS, SITE_ADMIN, ALL]).indexOf(scope) !== -1);
```

Comment: This example changes the behaviour of the initial function, which was returning a boolean. This one returns a scope. `.some()` could maybe work if that was the intent.